# "private method 'gets' called for "parker":String

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my code:

```
print "What's your first name"
first_name = "p".gets.chomp.capitalize!
puts "#{first_name}"
puts "Your name is #{first_name}!"
print "What's your last name?"
last_name = "m".gets.chomp.capitalize!
puts "#{last_name}"
puts "Your name is #{last_name}!"
print "What city do you live in?"
city = "world".gets.chomp.capitalize!
puts "#{city}"
puts "You live in #{city}!"
print "What state do you live in?"
state = "OR".gets.chomp.upcase!
puts "#{state}"
puts "You live in the state of #{state}!"
```

I keep getting this error though:

```
private method `gets' called for "p":String
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are trying to take input form user .. right ?

Answer (score 4):

There is a [`gets` method in `Kernel`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) and `Object` includes `Kernel`. That means that almost everything includes `Kernel` so almost everything has a `gets` method. The intent of a lot of the (private) methods in `Kernel` is to allow you to treat some methods (such as `gets`) as plain functions so you can say things like:

```
s = gets
```

to read from the standard input.

When you do this:

```
"parker".gets.chomp.capitalize!
```

You're calling the private `gets` from `Kernel` on a `String` but calling private methods with an explicit receiver is a `NoMethodError`.

If you want to read the first name from the standard input then you just want this:

```
first_name = gets.chomp.capitalize
```

Similarly for the other `gets` calls.